# C# couldn't find right fragment in text

Tags: c#, text, fragment

Need to find text fragment whitch contains condition: Need to find longest text fragment from text where words starts with the same letter as the last letter of the previous word (example: 1. my 2.years). i need to print out that fragment and the number of the line where he is in the text. my code:

```
public static string Longestfragment(string[] lines,char[] isolations ,ref int index)
{
    string longestSentense = "";
    int longestCount = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    foreach (string sentense in lines)
    {
        string[] words = sentense.Split(isolations); // split the words
        int count = 0;
        int line = 0;
        line++;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            // checking if the first word ends equals to the second word start
            if (words[i].Equals("") || words[i + 1].Equals("")) continue; // checking if one of the words not empty.
            if (words[i][words[i].Length - 1].Equals(words[i + 1][0]))
            {
                if (count == 0) //to find the start of fragment
                {
                    start = sentense.IndexOf(words[i][0]);
                    end = sentense.IndexOf(words[i + 1][words[i + 1].Length - 1]);
                }// to find the end of the fragment if the fragment if longer than 2 words.
                if (count >= 1)
                {
                    end = sentense.IndexOf(words[i + 1][words[i + 1].Length - 1]);
                }
                count++;
            
            }
            
        }
        // if there is the longest fragment we save it.
        if (count > longestCount)
        {
            longestCount = count;
            longestSentense = sentense.Substring(start,end-1);
            index = line; // to find the line index
        }
    }
    return longestSentense; //returning the value of longestfragment
}
```

if my text file is:

> hi my name is Sam. my years so good.

i get index 1( i think it should be 0) and the longest sentence (**is Sam. my years so good.**) it is right. but if my text file contains 2 or more lines like:

> equals sequence enter rope eight the.
>
> hi my name is Sam. my years so good.

my program just crashes or it print out wrong sentence. please help.

Comment: could you define exactly where the fragment is supposed to start and to end? Does it start at the first occurence of the two words with the same letter ending and beginning? where does it end? at the end of the line? at the next dot `.` ? what about `hi my name is Sam. my years so good. Never been better.` where does this fragment end?

Comment: @MongZhu it starts when the two words contains the condition like i said. and ends when the one word with one letter and other starts with different letter.

Comment: you get index = 1 as result because you increment `line` before the loop. How do you handle punctuation? what is the content of `char[]isolation` ?

Comment: @MongZhu char[] isolation = {' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t'}; that my isolation char array. i use it to split the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that is an option to you but searching texts for patterns can be done by regexes far more efficently and easily than doing it by loops.

I quickly hacked one together for you which will find all of your patterns in the text: [example regex screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5wVD.png)

```
\w+(\w)\s\g{-1}\w+
```

You could export all matches into e.g. a list and then search this list for the longest one.

Be warned though regexes can be extremly tricky and sometimes unpredictable. Mine most likely wwill not be failsave and also does not account for things like aword, danotherword as it doesn't account for punctuation etc.
But this should give a hint in a good direction.

**EDIT:**
[.NET directly supports regexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx). It's in the namespace:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is this line:

```
end = sentense.IndexOf(words[i + 1][words[i + 1].Length - 1]);
```

I believe it searches for the index of the last letter from the second word that fits your condition.

In this sentence:

> equals sequence enter rope eight the.

when `i == 4` you reach the words `eight` and `the`. If you search now for the index of the last letter of `the` => `e` [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) returns to you:

> The index of the first occurrence of value in array,

So you get `0` because your sentence starts with `e` and you run out of bounds in this line when you try to access an element at position `-1`:

```
longestSentense = sentense.Substring(start, end - 1);
```

**Solution:**

- I would suggest to calculate the end-index using the entire word and the method [`LastIndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return `33` for the word `the` because it starts at this point. You only need to add the length of the word and you have the end:

  end = sentense.LastIndexOf(words[i + 1]) + words[i + 1].Length;
- When you access the [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) from the sentence. The second parameter is `length` and not the end.

> public string Substring(int startIndex,int length)

So you would need to subtract the start index:

```
longestSentense = sentense.Substring(start, end-start);
```

- The start index is also posing the same problem like the end. First occurence!
  I would also suggest to search for the word and not the letter. Take for example this sentence:

> hi my name is Joe. my years so good.

Your fragment would start after `Joe.` with `my` but `IndexOf(String s)` would return the first `my`. You should calculate an offset that you keep counting up as you go through each word in the sentence:

```
if (Char.ToLower(words[i].Last()) == char.ToLower(words[i + 1].First()))
{
    offset += words[i].Length;

    if (count == 0) //to find the start of fragment
    {
        start = sentense.IndexOf(words[i], offset);
        end = sentense.LastIndexOf(words[i + 1]) + words[i + 1].Length;
```

- Furthermore does the second `if` condition not take upper and lower case letters into account so `s`==`S` will return `false`. You can force both letters to be of lower case to circumvent this:

The first 2 `if` conditions could be written a little more readable:

```
// do only if neither `null` nor `empty` nor `space`
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i] || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(words[i+1])
{   // access the last and first elements using methods with such names
    if (Char.ToLower(words[i].Last()) == char.ToLower(words[i + 1].First()))
    {

    }
}
```

- Increment `line` at the very end of the foreach-loop after the last `if` condition. This will give you the correct line.
- You should either put the `Substring` call into a `try catch` block or check whether `end` might be negative to avoid an exception:

  if (count > longestCount && end >= 0)
  {
      longestCount = count;
      longestSentense = sentense.Substring(start, end-start);
      index = line; // to find the line index
  }

Ok that was a lot of cleaning up. Have fun, I hope it helps.